Ignite Compute UriDeploymentSpi
I am trying to load a jar file using UriDeploymentSpi but the client node fails to start with the following exception. I have added the required dependencies for ALPN but still fails.
Any help on this is appreciated.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN$ClientProvider at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012) at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524) at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427) at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentClassLoader.loadClass(GridUriDeploymentClassLoader.java:56) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentFileResourceLoader.createResource(GridUriDeploymentFileResourceLoader.java:72) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:109) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.getClasses(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:71) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentFileProcessor.processNoDescriptorFile(GridUriDeploymentFileProcessor.java:388) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentFileProcessor.processFile(GridUriDeploymentFileProcessor.java:108) at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.UriDeploymentSpi$2.onNewOrUpdatedFile(UriDeploymentSpi.java:587) 
Tried adding all the required dependencies
